# If you are the first to manufacture / produce a product, can you later retroactively file a patent for it?

Tags: prior-art, prior-art-request

Scenario 1:

- I Started to manufacture and sell a product based on my unpatented invention.
- A year later, still I am the only manufacturer of this product.
- I then file a patent for it.

Will my patent be approved?

Scenario 2:

- I Started to manufacture and sell a product based on my unpatented invention.
- Within the same year, someone else has started to manufacture and sell this product.
- I then file a patent for it.

Will my patent be approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US there is a one year grace period from first publication or sale of an invention.  If you file up to the year exactly you might get a patent. There is no retroactive filing. You file when you file. A year plus a day is too late and the first sale might not be the start of the clock.

If you described it in detail in public or gave a demonstration of a prototype or put out a detailed advertisement then the year might have started earlier than you think.

Another issue is inventorship. You called it your invention. That is what is important, not the manufacture. Invention occurs at design-time of the product, not upon manufacture of the product. (Likewise, innovative manufacturing itself can also be patented if it makes possible a type of product-production that was not practical previously, but at some point the manufacturing process has its own design-time that predates the later manufacturing of the product.) The innovation (and thus the invention) occurs at the point you decided to deviate significantly from all prior art; that decision and envisioning of the better alternative occurred no later than design-time—not at point of manufacture, and definitely not in retrospect while selling the manufactured products.

Most of the world has no such grace period.

Comment: What about scenario number 2, where someone else has already started to manufacture your invention within the year?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages If you don't have a patent, you can't stop anyone else from manufacturing your product. If you wait a year plus one day from the first public disclosure to file a patent application, you will not get a patent.

Comment: I am aware that I cannot stop someone from manufacturing my invention if I don't have a patent. My follow up question was that if I can still get a patent if I file within 1 year of my own manufacturing but someone else has since also started manufacturing it. Which means that, once approved, I can then stop them from manufacturing it.

Comment: Yes    -  you can use the courts to try to stop them once you get a granted patent.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, thank you for integrating my edit into your answer, although the way that you did it denied me getting credit for my contribution.

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER - I’m not sure what edit or answer you are referring to. Is it the answer these comments are under?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, I made a mistake.  The edit has not been applied to your answer yet.

Comment: Your pending edit, if accepted, would be integrated into the answer exactly as *you* have integrated it into the answer. Normally answers are edited by others to fix the answer in some way not to expand the answer. To literally get credit for thoughts involving expanding someone’s answer you could post as a comment or you could post another answer that focuses on those thoughts. If your edit becomes accepted (by votes of participants) there will be an indication at the end of the answer that it was edited by you. People can click on it to see what you edited.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Since the proposed edit is to your answer, I'd prefer you to accept it or not.

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER The issue I have with your proposed edit, is the the moment of invention isn't important from the standpoint of starting the 1 year clock. The clock starts when you make the invention public.

Comment: I’ll look at it again later.

Answer (score -1):

If conception of the invention or reduction thereof to practice (hereinafter: “to Invent” or “Invention” etc.) occurs before March 15, 2013, and did so before anyone else, one may obtain the patent even if one hasn't filed for a patent thereon at any time provided someone else did file for and obtained the patent who was not the first to Invent since the first to Invent is entitled to the patent. This may occur through, for e.g., a lawsuit, or civil agreement. This pre-March 16, 2013 era was governed by the “first-to-invent" principle.

However, any invention since March 16, 2013, the full force and effect of the America Invents Act, would not have such opportunity to sue or seek a settlement as the "first-to-invent" rule was changed to a "first-inventor-to-file" except in case of theft. Even under this principle, one theoretically could sue if the facts can be established that what happened for another to file earlier was the result of conversion or even criminal theft of notes or other documents including the invention to "obtain" the patent through criminal and/or civil prosecution.

Accordingly, scenario 2 if occurred since March 16, 2013 would, indeed apply, but it is advisable to be ready to defend the position that one was, in fact, an inventor (and not a "patent thief").

Comment: There are problems with this answer. First “ If one invented the invention before March 15, 2013 in the U.S.,”  **No**. First where it is invented is not relevant, second the cut off date is tied to when filing occurred not when inventing occurred. If filed after that date AIA rules are followed, not if invented after that date. A main point if the AIA is to not care when invention occurred so it would be weird to use date of invention as a cut off.

Comment: Huh! What if an invention was first filed elsewhere, could a pre-AIA patent be still claimed in the U.S. just because a parent, say, was denied in another jurisdiction? (If you want, I’d ask it in a separate question)

Comment: The cut off depends on the claimed priority date so a foreign filing under the Paris Convention property Claimed for priority would determine if a U.S. application was AIA or not independent of the outcome of that application.

Comment: “Invention in the U.S. is generally defined to comprise two steps: (1) conception of the invention and (2) reduction to practice of the invention. When an inventor conceives of an invention and diligently reduces the invention to practice (by filing a patent application, by practicing the invention, etc.), the inventor's date of invention will be the date of conception.” If the date of conception is prior to March 15, 2013, AIA will apply.

Comment: The quote is a pre AIA definition. It ceases to apply for anything with a priority date after the 15th. And when it mentions “US” it means for US law not for things invented in the US. Where the invention took place has no relevance to this issue.

Comment: From MPEP. 2159.02 Applications Filed on or After March 16, 2013 [R-11.2013]
AIA 35 U.S.C. 102 and 103 took effect on March 16, 2013. AIA 35 U.S.C. 102 and 103 apply to any patent application that contains or contained at any time a claim to a claimed invention that has an effective filing date that is on or after March 16, 2013.

Comment: It does not explicitly say that 102 and 103 of AIA do apply to inventions conceived or reduced to practice before March 16, 2013. (I’ll post a question so you don’t fully have to explore a stand-alone question in comments maybe you’ll answer it)

Comment: I quoted the wrong section- now it is the right section.

Comment: I think the changes apply to all applications after March 15, 2013, except for those that vested the right of first inventor by conception or reduction to practice upon someone otherwise this would violate the Fourth Amendment’s Taking Clause, the Fifth’s Due Process Clause as it would be taking through retroactive legislation of thing protected under and through U.S. Constitution Art. I, § 8, cl..

Comment: Wow - a constitutional argument that no one else has made. Congress changed the law three years before it went into effect. See "*MPEP. 2159.02 Applications Filed on or After March 16, 2013*" It is 100% clear. To give the readers of SE an answer consistent with actual practice you should consider editing or removing your answer. Or at least add a preface that your answer is not consistent with current law and procedure but your reading of the constitution leads you to believe this is the way it should be.

Comment: The right to obtain the patent is established on conception; the "right", and its derivates, like the patent most directly, is what would be taken. I don't think there is case law that would deem this as not taking with retroactive legislation, and not only in situations like where one reduces the invention to practice or sets forth its specification, say a week prior to March 16, 2013, and someone else then files for a patent on or sometime after March 16, 2013, say in a few months even if that is one blatantly obvious case. I am intent to update the answer once I did more case-law research.

Comment: In the case you postulate the law would have been changed when it was signed about four  years before the conception. A case of conception before September 16 2011 when the AIA was signed but filing after March 15 2015 could possibly have made sense. They would need to show diligent pursuing of  reduction to practice for those 4 years or they would lose anyway.

Comment: As you acknowledge, effectively, there never was a need for making that constitutional argument because the statute is not unconstitutionally over-broad; a construction that “Applications Filed on or After March 16, 2013” proffering to mean that inventions with their effective date prior to March 16, 2013 should be also included would be result in the unconstitutional issues I see. But that’s not the case.

Comment: “Conception has been defined as ‘the complete performance of the mental part of the inventive act’ and it is ‘the formation in the mind of the inventor of a definite and permanent idea of the complete and operative invention as it is thereafter to be applied in practice....’ MPEP 2138.04, _quoting Townsend v. Smith_, 36 F.2d 292, 295, 4 USPQ 269, 271 (CCPA 1930) “ As long as the inventor satisfies the three requirements of conception, reduction to practice, and reasonable diligence, [their] date of conception is credited as the date of invention” and gets the patent regardless who files 1st[…]

Comment: […] Bumping Into Your Own Prior Art by PETER L. BREWER https://aipf.com/resources/News/2020%20August_Prior%20Art.pdf

Comment: So, in case the act of invention, at least under as the process was construed under the above three-prong test, is satisfied prior to March 15, 2013, the inventor will get the patent — either through patent prosecution, civil agreement with anyone previously deemed the good-faith patentee or applicant, or as a result of court decision.

Comment: No - a 1930 three prong test is irrelevant after a law signed in 2011 takes effect and changes the US to a first-to-file country.

Comment: That governs cases where the “invention” (as the term of art construed for purposes of the law during the pre-AIA era) was carried out prior to the effect of the law regardless of when the bill was passed. I actually find it hard to believe that the reduce-to-practice prong would be constitutional if not applied with a reasonability requirement or exceptions for good cause, extraordinary or exceptional circumstances. I think, really, it is a two prong test with the third prong effectively in the alternative.

Comment: It is a standard of “reasonable continual diligence”. Case law has accepted excuses and rejected excuses. They key thing is all if this is to decide an interference case between an earlier filer and a purported earlier inventor not to give a right to someone who has yet to file. Pre AIA.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Now we are in agreement.